# In Android what's the best practice to maintain a session through multiple activities?

Tags: android, session, cookies, android-activity

I have an app that has a log in screen then goes to other screens (in other activities), and needs to maintain a session throughout.

I've looked around and found a couple methods but most don't account for multiple activities.

I've found one using httpclient but it's old and Android is saying that it's better to use HttpURLConnection for newer devices.

So I'm not sure which one to use and how. Since all the other activities stem from a single activity I was thinking of making them all child activities to the login page and having them all reference the session through MainActivity.session (or whatever it's called).

Any advice?

Comment: What sort of "session"? Are you referring to some sort of session cookie sent by your Web server?

Comment: Yes, I need to maintain a cookie given by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session cookies are usually maintained by the HTTP stack that you are using. Activities do not necessarily play a role.

For example, if you read [the documentation for `HttpUrlConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), the "Sessions with Cookies" section shows you how to establish a cookie manager for your app:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Then, it does not matter what activity your HTTP operations are done on -- any relevant cookies from other operations, since your process started, will be included in subsequent requests.

Comment: Thank you! Now I wonder if there's something similar for httpclient.

Comment: @user2312638: For that, you would need a singleton instance of your chosen implementation of `HttpClient` (e.g., `AndroidHttpClient`). All requests made of the same `HttpClient` instance share cookies by default. This gets complicated, because HttpClient is not thread-safe by default, so you have to hook up a `ThreadSafeClientConnectionManger`.

Comment: Where do you set those 2 lines anyway? At the beginning after a connection?

Comment: And how do I find the origin server?

Comment: @user2312638: "Where do you set those 2 lines anyway?" -- somewhere once for your process. You could drop them in a `static {}` initializer block AFAIK. "And how do I find the origin server?" -- you are welcome to look through the JavaDocs for `CookieManager` and `CookieHandler` to see what information is available to you.

Comment: I put them in oncreate and my server's still not handling cookies. The server's trying to get attributes from an HttpSession and it's not getting them from the session made in the Android app.

Comment: Actually wait I think I see an issue, I'll try a fix.

Comment: @user2312638: Make sure you only execute those lines once, not once per activity, as each time you run time you'll wipe out previous cookies.

Comment: Ok I solved the issue, turns out I was still calling httpclient for one of them.